# Do non-ergodic chemical reactions exist?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

Do reactions whose final outcome is **not even theoretically predictable by any means possible** exist in Nature or does the outcome of all possible chemical reactions can (at least in theory) be **predicted** if we could get enough information about the conditions the reaction system is in?

My question isn't about a well-defined reaction system whose behavior is unknown to a certain degree but about the possibility *in principle* to discover a chemical reaction or a system of chemical reactions able to produce compounds which can't be predicted even in theory, even if we manage to acquire all the possible information about the system that can be acquired by all experimental means possible? What I want to ask is whether we can, at least **in theory**, know all possible products a reaction system can generate or do we "hit a wall" limiting our ability to predict certain chemical reactions over a certain limit?

I know very well the difference between a stochastic and a deterministic process, but what I'm asking isn't about stochasticity. It is about the possible **predictability** of all chemical reactions that could exist. As far as I know if we use the concept of stochasticity we may be able to derive possible, albeit only *probable* predictions about the state the system can be in. Therefore we can at least compute some probabilities different compounds can have to emerge under certain conditions. What I'm asking about is the validity of the concept of [ergodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity), therefore I want to know is it possible to know the end state and all the reaction products of **all** possible chemical reactions, or there are some which could generate products that are impossible to predict in both theory and reality? Do reactions generating such unpredictable behavior exist in the real world or are they possible only in theory?

Comment: What does ergodicity have to do with predictability?  I'm not clear on the distinction between predictability or stochasticity you are drawing either.  Nor is the precise meaning of "predictability" as you use it.

Comment: @CurtF., it means even if we can only predict the *probable* outcomes of a reaction it still **is** a prediction. In the context of the question it means are there reactions whose outcomes we can't predict even to a some probability. Are there reactions we can say nothing about even if we get to know all the conditions under which the reaction is occurring? Can there be reactions we can't know the outcome of?

Comment: If the system gets chaotic enough, it should be possible to get a system that is practically unpredictable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory). But you really need to refine your question. The way you state it here, it could be interpreted in lots of different ways, so I think it is really unfit to SE.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you shorten your question to a single, clearly defined point. For example here, it is not clear to me if you mean with "all conditions known" that **all information** (e.g. atom positions, velocities, exact wavefunction etc.) is known, or only reaction conditions (e.g. temperature, concentration, reaction time) and so on. What is the point of the question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to know are there reactions able to produce compounds we can't know of advance, even only in theory? Can there be a reaction able to yield totally surprising results, so we couldn't build a model predicting its behavior no matter how precisely we can measure the conditions it is in?

Comment: Practically there is, if the system is chaotic. And theoretically (even for "Laplace's demon") there is for the case of radioactive decay provided below. Everything else is philosophy and not really fit for discussion here.

Comment: I don't think the philosophers on the Philosophy SE section are fit for so *scientific* questions. I don't think they can even understand the question, too. It contains too much chemistry to be moved to the philosophical community.

Comment: @YordanYordanov Your inability to translate the question to philosophers doesn't make the question a good or well defined Chemistry question

Comment: @YordanYordanov Surprising or unpredictable are not defined in the context.Literally any chemical reaction is a probabilistic event, therefore unpredictable and there is a probability that leads to surprising results. If you create complex reaction networks, chaotic systems etc it is more pronounced, but it still there always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Life is an example of a series of chemical reactions with unpredictable results.**

Forget, for a moment, the long term evolution of living creatures and consider the chemistry behind inheritance and selection (at least one sexual activity has started). The key chemical reaction that drives the DNA code for the next generation is random mixing of the genetic material of the parents to generate the DNA of the next generation. This process clearly demonstrates that the result of a chemical reaction is not entirely predictable given the components (the code is written in the same language, but the combination in children is a random combination of the parent's DNA).

Over a longer time period, we can also observe that entirely new types of life emerge via Darwinian random variation and selection. Future life is hard to predict given the existing life at a given point in time. And the underlying process is a chemical reaction involving DNA.

So maybe it isn't natural to think of this as *chemistry*. But it is built of chemical processes and demonstrates that, in a sufficiently complex system, chemistry can deliver results that are not easily forecastable. Perhaps simpler systems can demonstrate the same point, but this one is staring us in the face as an existence proof.

Comment: ,I have never thought of crossingover in such a way. It really made an impression! Thank you for your thoughtful answer.

Comment: I only agree partially: Im principal you could calculate how the DNA evolves and recombines, or at least how probable a certain outcome is. In practice this just fails due to the huge amount of data points, but there are *not* infinitely many! You also could go the other way around: make the experiment and check whether you can calculate the outcome. Provided you have enough computer power and the apropiate level of theory, you can always calculate it. Because theory is supposed and designed to describe reality.

Answer (score 10):

The time point of the radioactive decay of a single atom cannot be predicted, even given all experimentally available information, and is not even predictable theoretically by any possible means.

Just isolate a single atom and observe its radioactive decay, and you have the purely random system you strive for. Could also take more than one atom and observe fluctuations with Geiger counter.

Comment: I agree with your example @deusexmachina, but my question is can we do the same for a chemical reaction?

Comment: @YordanYordanov You asked if processes occur in nature and radioactive decay reactions happen naturally in our environment all the time.

Comment: Then, do radioactive decay fall into the category of *chemical reaction*?

Comment: Of course: if 17F decays to 17O it has chemical consequences. Decay chains are in fact very important *chemically*, if you want to synthesize certain radionuclides.

Comment: I'm a little confused where is the border between chemistry and physics here. That is why I'm asking.

Comment: I think the radioactive decay *itself* is a physical process which leads to acceleration of the remaining nucleus. This acceleration will thereby cause a number of subsequent *chemical* changes.

Comment: The final outcome of radioactive decay is known in principle, event though there might be some uncertainty about decay chains due to paths that might not have been discovered yet. The change of the composition of radioactive material over time can also be predicted by the decay chains an nuclide life times.

Comment: @aventurin I know research evolves fast, so maybe I am not at the latest state of research. But I thought that it is not known when *a single atom* decays, but only the nuclide-specific half-life of a decay which is of course just a statistical property of many nuclides. AFAIK it  is not known if the decay is truly non-deterministic or caused by a hitherto unknown inner property.

Comment: @deusexmachina I think a way to restate your comment is that for any infinitesimal amount of time, we don't know if an atom will decay; we only know about decay (very well) in the limit of long time intervals.

Comment: @deusexmachina We don't know when any individual atom will decay, but we do know bulk properties such as "after one half-life, almost exactly half the atoms in a decently sized sample will have decayed with overwhelmingly high probability." The bulk process is completely predictable, so it's not clear (to me, at least) whether this really answers the question. One isn't usually looking at just a handfull of atoms.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well you have two ways to change that: a) lower the amounts of atoms, e.g. by diluting with inactive nuclide or b) lowering the time frame (random fluctuations in time). Essentially, radioactive decay shpuld be a perfect random number generator as the decay processes are indeterministic and perfectly decoupled.

Answer (score 4):

The ultimate fate of any [isolated system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_system) can be predicted since it tends to thermodynamic equilibrium. However, it might be that the time to reach the end state is such long that no one ever will be able to observe it.

For [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_system) and [open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_system#Open_system) systems things are more complex. But in principle it is possible to predict the "state" when the flow of matter and energy over time is known. Some of these systems may exhibit chaotic behavior, such that said "state" is actually a probability distribution over the possible states. That may be the reason why you have cited the concept of ergodicity.

Comment: How about kinetically controlled reactions then?